# The flag "in need of moderator intervention" is sometimes the only option in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, android-app

The flag "in need of moderator intervention" is sometimes the only option in the Android.

Example below, flagging the (now deleted) answer: https://superuser.com/a/1305357/116475

[image]

Typically there should be more for flag options:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> (now deleted) answer

That's the key. The answer got deleted in the interval between the page load and your flag attempt. The first stage of flagging is getting available flag options from the server. The server sends them based on the current post status, and the only way to flag deleted posts is for moderator attention.

This isn't specific to the app: the main site works the same way, although the site is more likely to update the post status via websockets.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I guess the issue is lack of post status update then as you mention.

Comment: The behavior described in the question is precisely how the desktop site used to work before they started including post deletion in the heartbeat.